# Node Notifier not working in production | what i am doing wrong?

Tags: electron, node-notifier

I am using node-notifier version 10.0.0. It is working fine when I run the app in development but it not working after build.

below is my code

```
notifier.notify(
        {
          appName: 'com.libonomy.wallet',
          title: 'Test',
          message: 'Current version is up-to-date.',
          sound: true,
          appID: 'com.libonomy.wallet',
          wait: false,
          timeout: 5,
        })
```

Please help me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What OS are you on? What packaging software are you using (`electron-packager`, `electron-builder`)? Are you signing your final installable? Do you have a valid .cer certificate? Have you considered doing notifications the way Electron suggests [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications)?

Comment: Windows 10 , electron-builder, yes i am signing final installable. yes certificate is valid. yes also used these notifications but its not providing actions for windows.

Comment: Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/issues/272#issuecomment-483030220) it seems like using [`electron-windows-notifications`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-windows-notifications) is your best bet, it supports action buttons too.